# Connect justgage-angular to encoded json data?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am using [justgage-angular](https://github.com/mattlaver/angular-justgage) to display my gauge data, how do i parse my php encoded json data to my gauge using angularjs.

HTML

```
<just-gage id="test1" min=0 max=120 value=100 title="TPD"></just-gage>
```

Instead of "value" having a static data, i would like to parse my encoded JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind that value to a $scope variable:

In your js:

```
$scope.currentValue = 100;
```

HTML:

```
<just-gage id="test1" min=0 max=120 value="currentValue" title="TPD"></just-gage>
```